# JavaScript object's properties undefined

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that has properties, but when I try to access them, it always returns undefined.

Using Chrome, I attached the object to window and in the console, if I do, `window.country`

It returns this object:

```
[ Object
currency_code: null
iso: "USA"
iso3: "USA"
name: "USA"
states: Array[51]
__proto__: Object
]
```

However, when I try to access a property, such as `window.country.iso` it's undefined.  Any ideas why this would be?

Thank you!

Comment: please show the actual code that highlights the actual setting/getting of your object.

Comment: You execute `window.country.iso` in the console?

Comment: Is `window.country` an array?  Do you need to do `window.country[0].iso`?

Comment: @Rocket yes, that was it, thank you! Weird chrome doesn't display that.

Comment: @dave It does display it. See the `[` and the `]`? That's it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `window.country` object is actually an array.

Chrome's console is showing you that.  As you can see your object is wrapped in `[]`, that means it's in an array.

Try to access it like: `window.country[0].iso`.